# Two users Having same HomeKit controller application installed on two different iPhone

Tags: ios8, homekit, ios-homekit

Two users Having same HomeKit controller application installed on two different iPhone.

**User 1** adds Home, Rooms, Zones and Accessories using the application and he can now control the Accessories, using the app interface.

**User 2** is in same environment (either in physical Home which has all the Accessories of user 1), But how can he control these accessories using the same app, how he will be able to see all the Rooms, Zones and Accessories added by the User 1?

How does HomeKit manages this multiple user accessing same Accessories scenario, or do we need to handle this scenario by our self in code?

Also how does it maintains the identity of the user with Home, that this particulate Home belongs to this XYZ user? As all the HomeKit user data is synced with iClod there should be some identity mapping for the Home entity.

Comment: Share homekit with another user: http://www.imore.com/how-share-homekit-access-other-people-guests-or-housemates

Answer (score 0):

I have done a much workaround for this.
First of all handling things by our own is not preferable for multiple users.

I had this query that how all configuration done on one device will reflect on another device for same home.
Unfortunately apple didn't provided much information on this and they also didn't clarify that Apple TV will require or not(As I have referred to some reports that says Apple TV will use as intermediator between iOS devices.

Now at application side i have tried to add User to home.
There is a HMUser class and we can add user to any home that we want to sync.
I was running my app in iOS 8.1 in both the devices, I was also logged in to icloud and keychain access was also enabled.

Now i have tried to add user using method of HMHome class

-addUserWithCompletionHandler()

I shows a popup in which we need to enter the email id of user to which we want to give access to current home.

But it didn't work. I always get error "notification not enable at remote side"

I think that login to Apple TV is require for adding user. I am not sure about this, Apple hasn't clarify on this too.
I don't have Apple TV if you have try to login in it and use two other iOS devices to give access to any icloud account.

Also revert me if it works.

Comment: I found out the way it is done, The admin user who creates the home layout need to add users to the application using the Apple ID of the users he wants to add as the guests. so internally HomeKit provides access to the Shared DB (Musty be using Cloud but not sure), to modify states of the Accessories in limited way.

Comment: Have you added user successfully ?

Comment: Yes, I have added home successfully, but my question was how to allow other users (adding guest users) to use the existing home. That we can do by adding user's Apple ID in the Application using HMHomeManager.

Comment: I have asked you about adding user not home... Anyway you can add user by addUserWithCompletionHandler() method. Try accessing using you home object. It will show a popup where we can add the email id of other users.